# Detect devices from the same local WiFi network

Tags: php, networking, ip, wifi

Im using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to detect the client's IP address in PHP.

If two clients share the same IP, is it safe to assume that they are either the same PC or from the same local WiFi network?

Are there any scenarios where the remote IP will be same even if the client's are from different networks/locations. (Ex. when using 3G or GPRS?)

Thanks :)

Comment: `Are there any scenarios where the remote IP will be same even if the client's are from different networks/locations.` This can not be possible..

Comment: `If two clients share the same IP, is it safe to assume that they are either the same PC or from the same local WiFi network?`.. DHCP won't allow this to happen. No two PC on the internet can have same IP Addresses as it will be used for the unique identification during the data communication..

Comment: @Hiren **Wrong.** There are a ton of machines which have the same *private IP* (in different networks) and a ton of machines which *share a public IP* at any given time. An IP is only unique within one specific network (segment), but there are millions of networks out there interoperating at once.

Comment: As far as I know, I have some sources which says that no 2 computers can have same IP addresses. referring this... http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Can_two_computers_have_the_same_ip_address

Comment: @Hiren Maybe you should read the rest of that article as well, not just the first sentence.

Comment: Oh fish... My teachers are teaching me wrong... nice.. But still this will make a confusion in the communication.. Thnx for the clearance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot assume anything. Two supposedly separate visitors sharing the same IP just means that they're traversing the same proxy/NAT device at some point. This may be because they're sharing a router in their home, because they're going through the same proxy at their company network (but may be miles and miles apart in different internal networks) or because their ISP is applying carrier grade NAT routing. This is not to mention VPNs, tunnels and things like TOR.

You cannot infer anything, really.

Comment: But what about the DHCP..? I mean it wont allow to have them a single IP address...

Comment: @Hiren Do you know what NAT is?

Comment: If I didn't know what is `Network Address Translation`, I wouldn't even asking about anything...

Comment: @Hiren So then you do understand the concept of several machines sharing one public IP...?

Comment: @deceze can i get ipv4 adress of machine . actually my project is for people who are not much technical so is thee a way to show ip of there machine . in Android app they will need it to connect to local machine

Comment: @simmi I cannot answer that based on a vague short comment. You should create your own question if other similar questions did not clarify this for you.